# Simple way to convert tuple wrapped as a string to a tuple in python

Tags: python, tuples

Given the string `'(1,2,3)'` read from a csv, how would I convert this to the tuple `(1,2,3)`? I tried `tuple('(1,2,3)')` but got `('(', '1', ',', '2', ',', '3', ')')` instead of `(1,2,3)`. I thought this might be reasonable since `int('1')` returns 1.

Now the code

```
tuple(map(int, re.split('[(),]', '(1,2,3)')[1:-1]))
```

works by returning `['', '1', '2', '3', '']`, trimming the edges, converting the entries to integers, and finally converting the resulting list to a tuple. I was wondering if there's a simpler way to do this, perhaps something analogous to int('1').

Edit: This solution fails if I have a stringed tuple that contains strings with commas or parentheses in it. I'd like something more robust.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Use [ast.literal_eval](https://docs.python.org/2/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval), it is  safer than `eval`

```
import ast
ast.literal_eval('(1,2,3)')
```

Result:

```
(1, 2, 3)
```

This can also work on lists, dictionaries, numbers, etc.

Answer (score 1):

If you trust your input, you may use `eval`

```
>>> inp = "(1, 2, 3)"
>>> eval(inp)
(1, 2, 3)
```

If you do not trust it, use `ast.literal_eval`, as proposed by "GWW"

Answer (score 1):

You can strip the `(` and `)` and then split based on `,`. Finally convert the list to a tuple with `tuple` by converting individual items to integer with `int`.

```
data = '(1,2,3)'
print tuple(int(item) for item in data.strip("()").split(","))
# (1, 2, 3)
```